# Silverlight 4.0 project won't load until I install the 5.0 SDK but won't build because it is missing 4.0 files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, msbuild

I'm trying to open a Silverlight project built on 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows Server 2012. When I try to load the project with the Silverlight 4 SDK installed I get the following error (message #1) when trying to open the .SLN file:

> "You need to install the latest Sivlerlight Developer runtime before opening Silverlight project [My Project Name]."

When I download the Silverlight 5 SDK, I no longer get the error (success... right...) but instead can't load a large number of .csproj files and am missing much of my solution. The error that is generated (message #2) in the **Output** window when attempting to load the additional .csproj files is:

> Unable to read the project file '[My Project Name].csproj'.
>   The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The files that it is looking for are included in the Silverlight 4.0 SDK :(

Has anyone experienced a similar error or have any insight into why VS is requiring me to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the Silverlight 4 SDK is not, or not properly installed. Did you check to see if 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" actually does exist on your system? Not just the directory, but specifically the Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets file. The directory might actually exist because it's create either by the Silverlight 5 SDK or Visual Studio, it does exist on my system even though I never installed the Silverlight 4 SDK...

If the file does not exist there, you probably need to install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7335) and try again.

Comment: I was suspicious of the same thing. Here's the deal, that .targets file exists in the directory related to the most recently installed SDK. When I install the SL 5.0 SDK to deal with error message #1, the .targets file is removed from the /4.0 directory and I start to get error message #2. If I install the 4.0 SDK to solve for error message #2, I get the missing .targets file back, but error message #1 appears again

Comment: I'm running VS2013 here, so it might not be a fair comparison, but I installed the SL4 SDK after the SL5 SDK and I'm able to open SL5 projects just fine. I'm guessing you still need to install the [SL4 Tools for VS2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18149), or the [SL5 tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28358). Those contain the developer runtime. Also, make sure you have SP1 for VS2010 installed...

Comment: after removing all the SDK installs and re-installing the SL4 SDK, SL4 Tools, SL5 SDK, and Expression Blend 4... I was able to get it to work. Initially I wasn't sure if SL4 Tools was included in SP1 or not. Had to install it from a separate .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, when I received the initial message I did the obvious which was to remove anything named "Silverlight" from Add/Remove before installing "Sivlerlight Developer runtime". I had Silverlight, Silverlight 4, and Silverlight 5. The idea is to leave the 4 and 5 versions and just remove the one without a number.